# Find Palindrome and print it (without using conditions)

Tags: shell, text-processing

```
!#/bin/sh

a=$1
b=$(echo $a | rev)

if [ $a == $b ]; then
   echo $a 
fi
```

I would like to write a script that will get an input some word and script have to find out if it is palindrome or not and if it is palindrome, it has to output that word.

Plus I cannot use conditions

I thought about writing the output into different text, use 'uniq' or compare it somehow else and print the output, but it seems to me too complicated ...

I will appreciate any advice.

Comment: `case $(echo "$a" | rev) in "$a" ) echo "$a is PALINDROME";; esac` might be one way to do this.

Comment: Why can't you use `if`?

Comment: It is not like I cannot use it, but my teacher told me that  I can solve the problem without it

Comment: I cannot use even 'case'. I will reedit the question

Comment: ... why not just ask your teacher? It would be the most honest and logical thing to do.

Comment: Well yes, but I have to solve my problem on my own.

Comment: @Muffy Asking here is not to do it "on your own" ;-)

Comment: You cannot do this without using "conditions". One way or another, your program will need to do one thing for a palindrome and another thing for a non-palindrome. It doesn't need to be `if`, but some sort of control flow statement will be needed. Unless you're allowed to pass the logic to an external program like `diff`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Let's play with the teacher:

```
$ a="anna";diff -sq <(echo "$a") <(echo "$a" |rev)
Files /dev/fd/63 and /dev/fd/62 are identical

$ a="arrna";diff -sq <(echo "$a") <(echo "$a" |rev)
Files /dev/fd/63 and /dev/fd/62 differ
```

Conclusion: If the word is a palindrome , diff will inform you so.

If you are not yet tought about process substitution then

```
$ a="anna" && echo "$a" >normal.txt && echo "$a" |rev >reverse.txt
$ diff -sq normal.txt reverse.txt
```

Comment: @Muffy Did this worked?